# Last piece of the puzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

> I'm trying to return the idselection attribute. Every time I run it
>   though I just get a lot of blank spaces. I've tried using the `find()`
>   method and `map()`. I just keep getting a lot of blank spaces. The HTML below is an example of what i'm trying to get

```
$('.mg-check.mg-checkEmpty.requireLogin').each(function() {
            var data = $(this).attr('selectionid');

            propVal = data;
            console.log(propVal);
            json.propVal = propVal;
        });
    }

<td class="mg-column8 pick borderRight last">
   <a class="mg-check mg-checkEmpty requireLogin" id="matchupDiv" name="matchupDiv" href="createOrUpdateEntry?" selectionid="mafdafd"></a>
```

Comment: You don't have a close quote on your name= attribute either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.mg-check.mg-checkEmpty.requireLogin').each(function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('id'); //note the change in this line

        propVal = data.text();
        console.log(propVal);
        json.propVal = propVal;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier and it returns an error saying                                   
`propVal = data.text();
                          ^
TypeError: data.text is not a function`

Comment: :))))))) I figured it out!!!!!! It's because the info I was trying to return wasn't a string so the `text()` wouldn't work! I've been working on this for the past 3 hours :)))

Comment: You know what, I didn't even notice the way propVal was structured.

But I'm glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your answer got me thinkin. Just needed some new perspective.